# search words without apostrophe (that have apostrophe)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a doubt.  In a search people search phrases with words with apostrophe and the searchs show results, but if people search the same phrases without apostrophe don't show results.

Example:

Search:  The Smith's cat is pretty
Results:  1

Search:  The smiths cat is pretty
results:  0

In other words, I need that when people search "The smiths cat is pretty", also show results, can I do in SQL for this type of searches?

Sorry my english.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: IS this searching for similar data in PHP strings, or in a database? If the former, consider using the levenshtein() - http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php - or metaphone() - http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php - functions

Comment: Is in database, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could try simply deleting apostrophes from the search query.

If you make:

```
$search_query = str_replace("'", '', $search_query);
```

The rest of the script could then look somewhat like this:

```
$words = explode(' ', $search_query);
foreach($words as $word)
{
  $pos = strpos($text_to_search, $word);
  if(is_int($pos))
    echo 'found word {$word} at position {$pos};
}
```

Of course, if you could provide a little more information about your current code, that would be good :) Is it possible for you to paste your current script in here ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try cut out special characters and then perform the search (for example str_replace all apostrpohes with nothing e.g. `str_replace("'", "", $str)`)

Should do the job for the purpose of searching, that is.

Comment: Thanks for your help, when the word is written without apostrophe no show results, only put results with apostrophe, I can to apply str_replace but would not show results

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding your english, could you post some code so i can understand the problem?

Comment: I guess what the OP has in the database is `Smith's` and he wants a result if he used `smiths` as the search term.

Comment: As i said , removing special signs such as apostrophe would solve the problem. You could also lowercase the string, but it would make much more case to have a case-insensitive search instead.

Comment: I updated my post.  When people searchs with smiths (without apostrophe) don't show results, when people searchs with smith's(with apostrophe) show results.

Comment: Ohhhh, the other way around. Thats a bit tricky, requires a lot of planning and string manipulation to get there, as far as i see it.

Comment: Thanks Mike Sanchez, you have understood my question.

Comment: Maybe you could try the same thing with SQL Replace. (Replace special chars in the fields you're searching in) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're searching in a database, then you should consider using Full Text Indexes.

Assuming MySQL, read up on

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

and particularly

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Could be a solution, I will review it, although it seems a bit hard to understand for me.

Comment: I put:  SELECT * FROM `employees` where match(lastName) against("smith" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) and show 1 result, SELECT * FROM `employees` where match(lastName) against("smith's" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) and show 1 result , SELECT * FROM `employees` where match(lastName) against("smiths" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) and don't show result (I need that show 1 result)

Comment: Please read this entry in the MySQL bug list - http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14194 and check that you're running MySQL >= 5.1.6

Comment: If you need more than that, then you may need to look at more sophisticated search tools such as Sphinx - http://sphinxsearch.com/

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but the way I have set up searches in the past is to store a "stemmed" field in the database containing whatever your trying to search, but cleaned and stemmed.

To clean I pass the data through this class, all it does is strip out any special characters, and a list of specific words that I don't want to include in searches:

```
<?php 
class Cleaner {

    var $stopwords = array(" find ", " about ", " me ", " ever ", " each ", " update ", " delete ", " add ", " insert ", " where ", " i ", " a ", " my ");//you need to extend this big time.

    var $symbols = array('/','\\','\'','"',',','.','<','>','?',';',':','[',']','{','}','|','=','+','-','_',')','(','*','&','^','%','$','#','@','!','~','`');

    function parseString($string) {
        $string = ' '.$string.' ';
        $string = $this->removeStopwords($string);
        $string = $this->removeSymbols($string);
        return $string;
    }

    function removeStopwords($string) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($this->stopwords); $i++) {
            $string = str_replace($this->stopwords[$i],' ',$string);
        }

        //$string = str_replace('  ',' ',$string);
        return trim($string);
    }

    function removeSymbols($string) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($this->symbols); $i++) {
            $string = str_replace($this->symbols[$i],' ',$string);
        }

        return trim($string);
    }
}
```

Then I stem the words using [an implementation of the porter stemmer algorithm](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/php.txt).

Then when searching you will need to stem the search words and compare against the list of cleaned/stemmed words in the database. Something simple like `SELECT * FROM search WHERE keyword LIKE '%$stem%'` would likely suffice.

This means that for example if you search for "daring" it would stem to "dar", so would produce the same results as "dare" and "dares".

Might not be explaining it all that well, but hopefully thats enough information to get you started =)